# Customize sparrow toolkit axis label

Tags: windows-phone-8

I like customize axis label style in sparrow toolkit. i wrate this code:

```
<sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
    <sparrow:CategoryXAxis Interval="1">
        <sparrow:CategoryXAxis.LabelTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="V" FontSize="12"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </sparrow:CategoryXAxis.LabelTemplate>
    </sparrow:CategoryXAxis>
</sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
```

i like replace static string "V" with X property value of Model object that i use to build the collection of points. i don't understand how to set DataSource and how to build it.

if i don't define DataTemplate, at run time i have the right X value, but i need change the color.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you try `Text="{Binding}"` ?

Comment: Yes, but i don't understand what object i must bind! i made several tests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `SparryChart`'s DataContext and bind your DataSource to it?

Maybe you can read the code here:[Column Chart](http://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/450191)

You can set `Text={Binding XProperty}`. XProperty is your binding property of your model. Have declare a property in your model? Then set your model as DataContext to your Chart control.